# Как задать условие цикла если структура конечного объекта(к которому приментся for) -меняется

Tags: java, циклы

Имеется такой код

```
String NameString;
int[] NameStruct = new int[64];
int[] StructSize = new int[2];
file.seek(offsetStart); 
NameString="";
StructSize[1] = (int)file.read();
count =(int)StructSize[1]-1;
System.out.println(count);
for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    NameStruct[i]= (int)in.read();
    NameString+=(char)NameStruct[i];
}
```

Он обращается к файлу - такой структуры `{[00][string]}`,первые 2 байта это StructSize, там записывается значение размера[string].

Проблема в том что у меня таких блоков несколько(их количество(выведено в переменную)), и я не знаю как это все обернуть в цикл, чтобы в нем была описана структура блока, но при этом `{[00][string]}` такой вид- блок принимает только в начале позиции обращения(файла), далее блок имеет другую структуру `{[00][00][00][00]*[00][string]}` *обозначает начало StructSize[00].

Каким образом можно решить это ?

Надеюсь нормально объяснил, если что могу пример привести !

Comment: Да уж приведи лучше пример.

Comment: пример -самой структуры - в хексе 05 4e 6f 6e 65 00 10 04 07 04 . [05] читается как единичное значение, и указывает на то что рядом это блок строка и ее размер -[05-1, то есть 4байта][4e 6f 6e 65 это стринг] [10 04 07 04 это новый блок 4 байта], 00 не читается. Я не очень понимаю как должна выглядеть проверка - в таком случае чтобы не было ошибок, ибо в моем коде - программа ожидает после String опять [00] из 1 байта, а там ей 4 байта, и только за ними снова StructSize из [00] и за ним реализовывается строка

Comment: Вы можете изменить текст вопроса (под вопросом и тэгами, ссылка "править"). Дабы вопрос был яснее приведите пример как входных данных (файл), так и ожидаемого результата (массив чисел? строка?).

Comment: Хотя блин проблему в целом, решил - но видно из-за моей неопытности  не пойму, почему но в цикле - массив  яро запоминает - последующую переменную и заполняет ее за предыдущей, то есть есть переменная Int A = 5, есть переменная B = String.SizeOf.A, на выходе в консоль имеем - A=Black, B=BlackWhite, C=BlackWhiteGreen, и так до конца цикла ! Как это ошибка называется и как ее решить ?

Answer (score 4):

Такие сложные циклы делаются с помощью универсальной конструкции:

```
for(;;) {
   //blah-blah
   continue; //пропустить хвост цикла
   //blah-blah
   break;  //выход из цикла
}
```

Некоторые товарищи предпочитают (если цикл должен быть исполнен хотя бы раз - постфиксный цикл):

```
do {
   //blah-blah
   continue; //пропустить хвост цикла
   //blah-blah
   break;  //выход из цикла
} while(...)
```

или если цикл может и не быть исполнен (префиксный цикл):

```
while(...) {
   //blah-blah
   continue; //пропустить хвост цикла
   //blah-blah
   break;  //выход из цикла
}
```

Comment: Вроде бы разобрался - но не пойму как это представить.Приведу пример -самой структуры, так как она представлена в хексе 05 4e 6f 6e 65 00 10 04 07 04 .
[05] читается как единичное значение, и указывает на то что рядом это блок строка и ее размер -[05-1, то есть 4байта][4e 6f 6e 65 это стринг] [10 04 07 04 это новый блок 4 байта], 00 не читается. Я не очень понимаю как должна выглядеть проверка - в таком случае чтобы не было ошибок, ибо в моем коде - программа ожидает после String опять [00] из 1 байта, а там ей 4 байта, и только за ними снова StructSize из [00] и за ним реализовывается строка

Comment: Сделайте несколько проверок - не пытайтесь все вложить в одно условие проверки, лучше всего условие проверки вкладывать в одно логическое значение типа `boolean flag` и проверяйте значение `flag` в цикле